# Regex Replace with one of the Multiple Regex Functions written

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a code where I have two regex functions to match two different patterns, and replace the matched pattern.

```
regex_afunction = (r"(?<=class).*?(?=\stest))
regex_bfunction = (r"(?<=\s\s\s\s).*?(?=\m_test))
regex_concat = ('|'.join([regex_afunction, regex_bfunction]))

with open(original_file) as f:
    with open(target_file,"w") as o:
        for line in f:
               match = any(re.match(regex_concat, line) for regex in regex_concat)
               if match:
                  print("Matching Loop entered")
                  match = re.sub(regex, 'xyz' , line)
                  o.write(match)
               else:
                   o.write(line)
```

So, if any of the regex function is a hit, it replaces the found variable with a user defined input(I have put xyz as an example and for a single instance)

```
Test File - 

class tester tests
    name_test m_test
```

I want to replace tester with a user input say xyz. and name_test as abc.

Can someone show me the way to do it?

PS- I am new to Python and new to SOF. I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Your question is unclear regarding what you expect to be written to the target_file.  Can you add that?  I see a couple of potential issues, but without knowing what result you are trying to achieve, it's hard to know how to propose a fix.

Comment: So, The target_file should replace tester (on line one) with a user input (say tester_2 ) and replace the name_test(on line two) with random_test.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the 2 regex patterns with a pipe character `|`

```
import re
filec =['class tester tests',
    '    name_test m_test']
pattern = r"((?<=class).*?(?=\stest))|((?<=\s\s\s\s).*?(?=m_test))"
for f in filec:
    print(re.sub(pattern,'xyx',f))
```

output

```
classxyxxyx tests
    xyxm_test
```

Comment: "pipe symbol" maybe